Is exponential cone solver more challenging to develop than second order cone solver?
I am a network engineer engaged in optimizing network functionalities and have observed a certain progression in the development of optimization solvers. Notably, it seems common for developers to first create solvers for second order cone optimization (or semidefinite optimization) and subsequently for exponential cone optimization. For instance, this development path is evident with solvers like MOSEK. Moreover, it appears challenging to find robust solvers for exponential cone optimization beyond MOSEK.
Therefore, out of pure curiosity my question is "Is exponential cone optimization more challenging to solve than second order cone optimization?"
This inquiry stems from the observation that the exponential cone is a type of non-symmetric cone, which I suspect might complicate the solving process for standard solvers like SDPT-3. Particularly, I think that numerical solver for symmetric cone cannot be reused on non-symmetric cone. However, my understanding is also conflicted by the notion that the difficulty level might be comparable since both problem types are convex.
Could anyone with experience or insights in this area kindly clarify this matter for me? A

Not all convex problems are of equal difficulty. Copositive Programs are convex, but in general, NP-Hard.

Thank you Mr @MarkL.Stone, I was quite supprise

Since the exponential cone does not belong to the class of symmetric cones, then the efficient primal-dual algorithm for LP, SOCP, and SDP does not generalize to the exponential cone case. In that sense, the exponential cone case is harder.
However, based on an idea of Levent Tuncel, then a practical efficient primal-dual algorithm that mimics the algorithm for symmetric cone case has recently been suggested.

Thank you can exponential cone be solved in polynomial time like socp ?

Yes. A self concordant barrier is known that can be evaluated in polynomial time.

Thank you so much ! Can you give me some reference on the fact of " A self concordant barrier is known that can be evaluated in polynomial time" . I have already upvoted your answer .

Really weird since someone already provided you the answer in previous reply to a post of you:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4924449/what-kind-of-interesting-properties-that-make-exponential-cone-attractive Have forgotten about that?

Oh ny bad ! I see it now
